# Big O Notation-Please explain O(log2n)

Tags: java, for-loop, big-o

I'm having trouble understanding why this piece of code is O(log 2^n) for its Big O Notation:

```
for (int i = n; i>=1; i=i/2){
    sum = i+j;
}
```

I thought it would be O(n).

Comment: What part is confusing? Notice `i = i / 2`?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch i saw the for loop and i thought it just would be 0(n). I don't get the significance of i = i / 2 in the for loop. I know i gets divided by 2 (Does it divide by 2 in every single loop in the for loop?)

Comment: @sukiyo: It divides `i` by 2 every time it goes through the loop, so if `i` starts as 1024, then it'll be 512, 256, 128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1, then 0 (because of integer division), at which point the loop exits. So every time `n` is doubled, you'll get 1 more iteration before the loop exits. That's the definition of `log (base 2) of n`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is `O(log_2 n)`. Because it will run until `n` becomes 1.

After k th step suppose the whole things become 1.

So `n/2^k = 1`

`k=log_2 n`

The complexity is `O(log_2 n)`

Comment: is the n/2^k the i = i/2 part?

Comment: @sukiyo.: Yes on every step you are basically dividing n by 2. You got it right

Comment: thank u so much. i dont understand how to write that in log form though. where did the n/2 go?

Comment: where did it go means? On every iteration the value of n (which is stored in `i`) decreases..like at `first i=n then i=n/2 then i=n/4 then i=n/8...`

Comment: so its not log(2n) (or log(2^n))? My teacher's handwriting is kinda bad but he definitely wrote a 2n or 2^n.

Comment: @sukiyo yes it is `log_2 n` with base of `2`

Comment: I think it'd be more clear to use either `lg n` or `log2 n` notation. Log means log base 10. Ln means log base e

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer:

As @coderredoc explained this code snippet is O(log n). Base of logarithm is immaterial in asymptotic notations because it only make difference of constants.

In-depth answer:
If this is asked in the academic context; then please read more about difference between big-O notation and big-Θ notation.
http://web.mit.edu/16.070/www/lecture/big_o.pdf
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Matters_of_notation

For your specific question, any code which is O(log n) can theroritically said to be O(2^n) or O(n) or O(log 2^n). Because, big-O notation describes the upped bound and not the tight bound.